# org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${driver}'

Tags: java, spring

I am a beginner in spring. Here is my **beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="DB.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${uname}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${pwd}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**And DB.properties is given below:**

```
#database connection propertiess
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Payment
uname=root
pwd=renu@193
```

**I am getting this error given below:**

```
        Apr 04, 2014 11:07:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${driver}'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.student.spring.test.RunClass.main(RunClass.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${driver}

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 3 more
```

I know what is this error. This error is about class BasicDataSource.  This class is not found...... but i already included the required jars in build path in my project.
Jars is as given below......
a)/home/praveen/Downloads/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
b)/home/praveen/Downloads/org.apache.commons.pool.jar

I have read some where that may be the version of jars causing the problem... and interfering with each other.....

The jars are already available in project build path.... Please help me to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated by me....

**The RunClass.java is given below:**

```
package com.student.spring.test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class RunClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("beans.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);


        BasicDataSource bds = (BasicDataSource) factory.getBean("myDataSource");        
        Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = bds.getConnection();
            System.out.println(bds.getDriverClassName());
            System.out.println(bds.getUrl());
            System.out.println(bds.getUsername());
            System.out.println(bds.getPassword());
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where on the classpath is your `DB.properties` resource?

Comment: It is in my src folder of the project in eclipse IDE

Comment: Show us your `RunClass` class.  How are you loading your `beans.xml` context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check your jars once, is spring-expression.jar there?**

And create applicationContext like below and check

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

BasicDataSource bds = (BasicDataSource) context.getBean("myDataSource");
```

Comment: It is not loading your DB.properties file. Can you check once.

Comment: After applying your code... i am getting error given below

Comment: Exception in "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:439)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83).RunClass.main(RunClass.java:19)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor

Comment: add spring-expression.jar to your classpath

Comment: i added org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar in my classpath. But again i am getting another error...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL

Comment: there is some mismatch with your jar files, please check

Comment: what type of mismatch, is there any dependecy issue in jar's

Comment: I have 6 jars in my classpath which is as given below :

Comment: spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar org.springframework .expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar ... Please suggest what should i do to correct the mismatch

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression/3.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: another error after adding 3.1.0 jar : Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [DB.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: it is not finding DB.properties file in classpath, check once

Comment: sir i have solved the question,on this link forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/26798-classpath-context-xml-with-file-system-properties, I have got the solution.. in the statement given below : <property name="location" value="classpath:com/springinaction/chapter03/jdbc.properties"></property>
SO, full path is required for properties file.. very very thank you. You helped me lot. THANK YOU ONCE AGAIN.....

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using maven, make sure if your DB.properties is in location as below:

```
    src-|-package1
        |-package2
        .
        .
        .
        |-packageN
        |-beans.xml
        |-DB.properties
```

else specify your full classpath for  file location as:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:packageName.jdbc1.properties" />
</bean>
```

and then change your code as pointed by @Sotirios and @Ramesh:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    BasicDataSource bds = (BasicDataSource) ctx.getBean("myDataSource");
```

Comment: Oh, you figured it out.

Comment: And yet he accepted an answer that didn't work for him instead of yours.

Answer (score 1):

[`XmlBeanFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html) is a deprecated class since 3.1 and a [`BeanFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html). A `BeanFactory` is only responsible for generating beans. The task of processing (or rather registering the processes for processing) beans belongs to `ApplicationContext` subclasses.

Therefore use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to produce your beans and retrieve them

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");
BasicDataSource bds = (BasicDataSource) ctx.getBean("myDataSource");
```